# Vuetify equivalent of a UINavigationController

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a component that has a view stack much like a `UINavigationController` for iOS and MacOS. I need to be able to push views onto the stack and let the user pop them from the stack by pressing a back button. Does Vuetify have a web component similar to this?

Comment: I ended up using `v-tabs` and `v-tabs-items` which effectively achieved what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify is a UI framework.

You need something like [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/)